# How can I reboot a zyxel pk5001z (Firmware version CZP002-4.3.009.16) via ssh

Tags: zyxel

For some reason this router gets terribly slow via the http configuration site and needs rebooted.  I can login via ssh but can not get it to reboot.  "sys reboot" does not work.  Maybe I need to change mode some how.  But I can not find a CLI reference manual for this version online either.

Please help me figure out how to reboot this thing via ssh.

Thank you.

Comment: I replaced the router with a different brand.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a full shell, so no `shutdown -r now`

I did find the CLI Reference Guide for ZyXEL and it looks like the command you need is just `reboot` Section 39.3 here http://www.manualslib.com/manual/363430/Zyxel-Communications-Zywall-Cli.html?page=343#manual

Comment: reboot does not work.  responds with "reboot: no"
shutdown -r now responds with -sh: shutdown: not found
The above link is to the ZYwall device which is different than the PK5001z.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: Good catch. Have you tried running `help` or `?` to see what it responds with

Answer (score 2):

Just so the answer is here, you can do

```
$> su - admin
```

pw: 1234

This should drop you into a limited shell. You can type ? to see a list of commands.

> ZySH> reboot

Comment: Trevor I replaced the router as it just was too unreliable for my application.  So now I don't know if that would work.  The ? lists commands but none of which are reboot.  But maybe after I su the list would change.

Comment: If it's the same brand/modem it should work.  No promises on different brands.  As an aside, I found the PK5001z to frequently stop routing DNS information and I can't get root to troubleshoot further without following some hacky guidebooks.  So I switched back to a C1000a.

Comment: I switched to a TPLink that supports bandwidth control.